# How to develop for multiple websites in parallel?

Tags: php

If it makes any difference, I am using Xampp on windows for my web server & PHP (all web pages are PHP based, some include JS, all include CSS file).

The point is that I have a local directory which represents `http://localhost` and if I want to develop multiple websites I have to copy them all under that directory.

And since most of them have CSS, images and many have JS, I end up with the images/JS/CSS for all websites mixed in to `http://localhost/images`, `http://localhost/css`, etc.

And when I come to upload them it's a nightmare. I am worried that I might forget to upload some vital files, or to upload files that do not belong to the site.

What's the solution?

In my case, all files are PHP, so should I tweak `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but I wonder what the general approach by professional web designers is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set up `VirtualHost`s, so you can visit http://foo.local or http://bar.local (example names of websites/projects you're working on) on your local machine, find your Apache configuration file (named httpd.conf in Apache1.X or apache2.conf in Apache2.X).  This file tells you where your virtual hosts live (usually with an `Include` directive on the bottom of the file).

Let's assume the project you're working on is foo.com.  You'll need to add this to either the bottom of your httpd.conf/apache2.conf files or as a new file in your virtual hosts directory (just name it something appropriate like foo.com.conf or foo.local.conf or something).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@foo.local
    ServerName foo.local
    DocumentRoot /where/your/website/files/are
    ErrorLog /where/your/logs/go/foo.local-error_log
    <Directory /where/your/website/files/are>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(where "/where/your/website/files/are" is the directory where your current project is, where "/where/your/logs/go/foo.local-error_log" is any directory/file that you'd like to store your logs in, where the location in your `<Directory>` directive is the same as the location of your `DocumentRoot`)

Then you need to restart Apache.  If it complains, look at the error and try to fix it based on what it says.

Then you need to add a fake host to your hosts file so that when you visit http://foo.local in your browser it points to your local computer.  The hosts file is `/etc/hosts` in Linux/BSD/OS X/Solaris or `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts in Windows`.  You'll need to edit this file as root / with sudo or pfexec (in BSD/Linux/Solaris/OS X) or as an Administrator in Windows.

Add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 foo.local
```

To the bottom of this file (or anywhere that makes sense, as long as it's on it's own line).

Here's some more info to get you going:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with virtual hosts. See [this tutorial](http://www.tildemark.com/software/servers/setting-up-virtual-hosts-with-xampp-running-on-windows-xp.html) here for how to set up virtual hosts on windows with xampp.

Then, you can emulate host names by editing your hosts file. You can add fake names that refer to your site. I like to use the `.tst` top level domain which is not real so it won't interfere with anything. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.ehow.com/how_5225562_edit-windows-hosts-file.html) for Windows on how to edit your hosts file (not sure what version of windows you're using?):

So, if you had two sites, let's call it `site1` and `site2`, you set up two virtual hosts, call them `site1.tst` and `site2.tst`. Add the virtual host definitions in xampp, and then add those names to your hosts file to refer to `127.0.0.1` (localhost). This allows you to go to `http://site1.tst/` and `http://site2.tst/` in your browser.

Comment: Good tutorial linked to, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Make directorys `www/Project1` , `www/project2` etc and put the contents likewise.. Now the point is that if you want to take the first project, go to http://localhost/project1. All th php files, css, images etc for project1 will be inside the folder www/Project1.. Similarly your project2 will be accessed through http://localhost/project2

Comment: Yes, if you're using relative links/scripts/images etc. you could simply make directories in your current DocumentRoot as well (so like @NBK said: you could simply go to http://localhost/project1 or http://localhost/project2).

Comment: +h, each, though, for taking the time to try to help

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a Virtual Host for each of your local websites. With this solution **you don't even have to copy your sites to your xampp/htdocs** folder.

Read this article, it covers everything:
http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/

You have to edit 2 files, and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Use virtual hosts. And set up a local host entry for a domain name for each site like `example.local`

Comment: Virtual hosts work great.  Also, for your image problem, create folders for each project, with multiple image folders in each.  Same with javascript, css, etc.

Comment: This is a good idea, but you told them absolutely nothing about how to do it and then were a dick about it when they asked how.

Comment: yeah i was kind of a dick... +1

Comment: It kind of sucks when you see people asking questions that you know exist on the internet in public knowledge, but I have to assume a) they've already Googled the hell out of their question and probably found nothing, and b) they still need help.  I think something more useful would be to search S.O. or Google for them, as you *know* what are good resources and what are crap, having had more experience.  Just saying.  There was a time when I didn't know this stuff, and I can relate - nobody's born with it.

Comment: @prodigitalson sorry that I didn't do more research U& thanks for talking the time to reply. I have +1 you everywhere possible. Thannks

Comment: @dan: there was a time when i didnt know either, i havent forgotten that and there are tons of things i dont currently know (hence my presence on SO)... however after you give someone the proper terms they should be able to find it on their own (9/10 times if you cant find info on something widely documented via a search engine its because you dont know the proper terminology). That said i could have posted direct links or a full crash course on setting it up.